# "this is going to be the first time" + future simple

Tags: future-constructions

I hear that the future simple is not to be used with the "This is going to be the first time"

**This is going to be the first time I will drive a truck.** wrong

Natives say it should be:

**This is going to be the first time I will have driven a truck.** correct

However, I have two examples from reliable sources which employ the future simple.

**Probably that is going to be the first time I will be able to sing.** by J. Vernon McGee

I think that the reason for permission to use the future simple in the last sentence is due to the verb "to be". Do you agree with my contention?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you hear (or read) that sentences such as

> This is going to be the first time I will drive a truck.

are wrong?  I would prefer to include "that" resulting in

> This is going to be the first time **that** I will drive a truck.

but the shortened form follows a quite common pattern. I see nothing wrong with it. I see no need for special conditions to give "permission" to use such a construction.

The suggested alternative:

> This is going to be the first time I will have driven a truck

seems to me both more awkward, and significantly less likely to be used by a fluent speaker. I think the original is better.

Comment: I was exposed to this idea on a few language forums.